# Primefaces override doesn't work after non ajax refresh

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, overriding, locale

I'm faced with an annoying primefaces-bug. I have 2 commandLinks for changing languages:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{language.setLanguage('de')}"
                            ajax="false">
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/flags/germany.png"
                                style="vertical-align: middle;width:40px;height:34px" />
                        </p:commandLink>
```

if I change the locale now, the page is reloaded but it seems like the primefaces overrides are gone. At least the texts are bigger... Is this a familliar issue?

regards

Comment: what primefaces version?

Comment: sorry, forgot about the versions. I am using PF 4.0 and jsf 2.2

Comment: the strange thing is that only the column headers and it's content is getting bigger, the rest stays as it is (and should)...

Answer (score 0):

I would have just commented, rather than posting an answer but I'm lacking the points :).

If you are seeing styles disappearing when changing locale, I suspect is it your resource locator that may be the cause. Per JSF 2.1 specification, Section 2.6.1.3 ([JSR-000314](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr314/index2.html)) a resource identifier can consist of the following elements

```
[localePrefix/][libraryName/][libraryVersion/]resourceName[/resourceVersion]
```

Assuming you have a style sheet `app.css`, using

```
<h:outputStyleSheet library="css" name="app.css" />
```

would locate the resource at `<root>/resources/css/app.css`. I suspect if you programmatically change the local to something other than your default locale, say Italian (i.e. `it`), then JSF will look for your resource in `<root>/resources/it/css/app.css`. Its only a hunch. I just recently started looking at what is requires to do localization and I recalled JSF having a means to organize locale-specific resources.