# PrimeFaces css override stop working after non ajax request

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

This question is just the same as: [Primefaces override doesn't work after non ajax refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832525/primefaces-override-doesnt-work-after-non-ajax-refresh) who wasn't corrected answered.

This is happening:

I have this page: which have the desired look

[image: CSS Working]

And then when I add a document which does a non-ajax request it looks like this:

[image: CSS Not Working]

I'm adding the css libraries like this in the head:

```
    <h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="general.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="mEstilo.css"/>
    <ui:insert name="recursos"></ui:insert>
    <title><ui:insert name="titulo">mGestion</ui:insert> - mGestion</title>
    </h:head>
```

The only situation where the css stop working is there, after a non-ajax request, when I press this button:

```
  <p:commandButton id="b_crearDocumento" value="Aceptar" actionListener="#{iniciarProcesoController.crearDocumento()}" 
 disabled="#{!iniciarProcesoController.esDocumentoValido}" oncomplete="w_verImportarD.hide()" ajax="false">
  </p:commandButton>
```

That is an accept button for upload a document, with this fileUpload:

```
    <p:column>
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{iniciarProcesoController.imagenListener}"
                                      mode="advanced" auto="true" update="p_botones"
                                      sizeLimit="20971520"/> 
    </p:column>
```

The document is uploaded fine, that's the only problem with this process, the css got messed up.

Comment: I don't see any differences... and how is this ajax related? You say it fails in a **NON**-ajax request. And how is it jquery related?

Comment: or is it the 'height'? Then you certainly have to show an mcve

Comment: See the two PanelGrid below Iniciar Proceso. Their padding and margin had like 5px and now it have like 0px, the text is closer to the edge (not a 30stm reference). Also the left blue bar is shorten. Wait, I forgot to add the button code. That's why ajax was related, because that all got screwed just after I press that button, which does a non ajax request. Just updated the question, thank you.

Comment: The button does a **NON**-ajax request, so it is not ajax related. And did you check if css was not reloaded on a submit?

Comment: I don't know how to check that. But I just notice that it's not PrimeFaces whom override my CSS, It's my CSS who overrides the PrimeFaces one. This look and feel is the same that I get when I declare my outputStyleSheet on the body instead of the head. Just removed the ajax tag, you won lol